# WordPress Video Upload HTTP Error (IIS SERVER)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, iis, file-upload

I am trying to **upload a video** on WordPress. after 100% uploading it gives HTTP Error.i had exceeded limit from php.ini. solution working fine for small videos like 2-6 mb but for 20 mb video it causes HTTP Error.
please refer this error image screen shot
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxhpn.png**

I am using **IIS Server**. I tried so many options like :

```
 wp-config.php file: define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB');
```

/* following htaccess options */

```
1. AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

2. <IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
   SecFilterScanPOST Off
   </IfModule>

3. # Exclude the file upload and WP CRON scripts from authentication
<FilesMatch "(async-upload\.php|wp-cron\.php|xmlrpc\.php)$">
    Satisfy Any
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from none
```

4 . AuthType Basic
    AuthName share
    Satisfy Any
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

**Any Help is Appreciated.**

Comment: try wp-config.php file: define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128MB'); or upload the video via ftp

Comment: On the server check the IIS logs for the sub-status code and the Windows Event logs for any entries related to the request. IIS has an upload limit of 30000000 bytes by default, but it would send a 404 not a 500 if you exceed that.

Comment: @meck373 : Not Working

Comment: @PeterHahndorf  yes i had exceeded the IIS limit by 2gb. so how can i solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with exceeding the allowed request content size in IIS which is 30000000 bytes.

Create a file `web.config` in the root of your site with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="50000000" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If such file already exists, add the XML node with the maxAllowedContentLength attribute.

You can also use IIS Manager, select your site, double-click `Request Filtering` and `Edit Feature Settings...` on the right. Change the number for `Maximum allowed content length`.

Don't set it too high.